# Wrong encoding when executing .jar on VPS machine in scheduler (cron)

Tags: java, cron, vps

When I execute Java program as a user in terminal with command:

```
java -jar progName.jar
```

I receive stable and workable program which writes info to some files. But when I wrote some commands for cron scheduler to execute this program regularly, program works fine, but text in files is written in wrong encoding and I receive not the text but `???`.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on my server machine.

Comment: I mean wrong encode. That is just my bad english knowledge..

Comment: What does `file` say about the "bad" output files? What does `xxd` (or `hexdump -C` or `od -x`) say about the output files?

Comment: This issue is depends on OS default encoding. If you didn't define direct encoding when write to file, it uses default OS encoding. So, add encoding  for characters when you write data in file in your app.

Comment: I guess the `cron` job is running with `LANG=C` and when you run it locally it might be `LANG=ru_RU.utf8`. So change the locale setting for the `cron job`. e.g. create a script which execute your Java program and set the locale before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and tips. I solve this problem using a comment of user eg04lt3r:

> This issue is depends on OS default encoding. If you didn't define direct encoding when write to file, it uses default OS encoding. So, add encoding for characters when you write data in file in your app.

So, I added encode way to my writer in Java program, and now everything works fine.